# How to make backend accessible only from Frontend in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

For my frontend, I have an angular application which consumes data from a node.js backend through an http call: `http//server:3000`.

With my current setup and config or a different setup if needed, how can restrict the backend from being **accessible** **only** to the frontend and **inaccessible** via any channel i.e it shouldn't be reachable by any Postman request or via browser etc but only reachable within the frontend app.

Dockerfile for the Frontend:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Dockerfile for the server:

```
FROM  node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /server
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
services:

server:
  container_name: server
  image: server
  build:
    context: ./server
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes: 
    - ./server:/app
  expose:
    - '3000:3000'

client:
  container_name: commerce
  image: commerce
  build: 
    context: ./
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes: 
    - ./commerce:/app
  ports:
    - 8080:80
  depends_on:
    - server
```

I'm wholly unfamiliar with networking in docker so detailed suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally the frontend runs in a browser.  Your `client` container doesn't actually run the client code, it just provides a copy of it that runs in an end user's browser.  The backend _must_ be accessible to a browser (maybe via a reverse proxy) if this is your setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze, how can I setup a reverse proxy for the backend to be reachable only to the frontend?

Comment: There's not a good way to make an API accessible to an application running in an end user's browser but not to tools like `curl`.  This is true with or without Docker, and Docker doesn't provide any way to "tunnel" a request from a browser into the Docker network.

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate the communication between server and client by using `docker bridge network`. According Docker Documentation: a bridge network uses a software bridge which allows containers connected to the same bridge network to communicate, while providing isolation from containers which are not connected to that bridge network.

I.e. Only services defined in docker-compose.yaml can reach backend server if they use defined `backend` bridge network, e.g. your client. Note! Server port is not mapped and exposed to be reached. You can reach your client from e.g. browser on `8080` as we map and expose it with `ports: -8080:80` in docker-compose.yaml for client service.

**Note!** It only works if the requests are processed and sent from frontend container and not from browser.

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:

  server:
    container_name: server
    image: server
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes: 
      - ./server:/app
    networks:
      - backend
  
  client:
    container_name: commerce
    image: commerce
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes: 
      - ./commerce:/app
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - server
    
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

You can reach backend server from client container with its service name, i.e. `server`. E.g.:

1. Verify that you can not reach server from host e.g. in browser entering `localhost:80`
2. Start both container with above docker-compose.yaml in detached mode.

```bash
docker-compose up -d
```

3. Start a bash instance in client container.

```bash
docker exec -ti <image-name-or-id> bash
```

4. Verify you can reach server with its service name and internal port number (i.e. within network bridge)

```bash
curl server:80
```

Comment: Compose provides a network named `default` for you; you don't need to change your `docker-compose.yml` file (except possibly to delete the `ports:` you don't want accessible).  See [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for more details.

Comment: When I change my compose file to reflect the yours @m19v, the frontend if accessed from the browser is unable to retrieve the data from the backend. I get an

Comment: @DavidMaze, I'm not actually sure how the frontend would be able to call the backend if I delete the ports that I don't want to be accessible. Could you perhaps explain a bit more or share a compose file that illustrates how, I can achieve my aim?

Comment: @Nii Have you debugged to what endpoint are the requests sent? You have to change the base uri/endpoint in client to your backend service name.

Comment: @m19v, yes I changed the base url in the client to reflect the change i.e ```http://server/```. But it fails in the browser. I confirmed from both the console and network tabs.

Comment: Is the port also correct, i.e. 80?

Comment: Yes, the port is also set to 80 in the client code

Comment: can I share the repo with you so you could give it a try, if you have time to spare?

Comment: I can have a look but it does not help, i.e. the comment of @DavidMaze is here the case. The requests from client to server are being sent from browser not from frontend container. My answer only work if the e.g. rest requests are processed and sent from frontend container. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: The options to your case would be either to set up a reverse proxy or work with ssl certificates and allow backend only accept requests from trusted party, e.g. client

Comment: I understand but I'll need request been from the client to the server accessible and inaccessible when tried elsewhere but that's what I don't know how to achieve.